# Fast Search Not Returning Results from a Specific Record Library

Tags: fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

We're expecting FAST Search to return results from a Record Library but it's not. The Record Library has permissions set at the folder level. We didn't set any exclusion rules. We weren't able to find out any helpful info in the crawl log history & FAST logs.

Do you have any suggestions how to further troubleshoot this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Not useful as in no log entries for that library/folder or did you get some other message in the crawl log?

Comment: No log entries for that library/folder..

Comment: Check library settings if it's marked to be excluded. Only rationale to me if there is not a crawls rule preventing it. And I guess you have tried a full crawl as well(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were already doing incremental crawls but a full crawl solved the problem. We did not do an index reset, just a full crawl. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Library settings and make sure search option is not off.

go to Library settings > advance Settings > middle of the page you will see Search headings, make sure it is turn of(select Yes).

[image]

Comment: Yap, it's turned on.